# How to produce a tag cloud for Google Custom Search?

Tags: search, tag-cloud

I want to populate a tag cloud with frequent search queries submitted to my websites Google Custom Search based search engine. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tag cloud service such as [this one](http://www.tagcloud.com/). You'll have to log all the queries being searched for though, as the custom search api won't give you the search logs. In order to do that, you'll need a wrapper around the search box to intercept all searches before sending them to Google.

Comment: Interesting but how to get the "service" running? I don't find any link to any resource that can help in their website.

Comment: @Wassim I've never used it. I also found this question: [Tag Cloud web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339356/tag-cloud-web-service) which offers some useful links.